# Templated check for the existence of a class member function with argument list?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, sfinae

Similarily to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/templated-check-for-the-existence-of-a-class-member-function) is it possible to use SFINAE to determine if a type has a member function with a certain argument(s)? Without the argument list as answered in the other question and the [`std::void_t` example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t) says it works fine. (I stood with the latter.) However, If I try to add a check for argument lust with extra `std::decltype<>()` it fails with `template parameters not deducible in partial specialization`. Is there any way to extend this method to check for certain argument types?

Example code:

```
#include <type_traits>

class A {
public :
    void a(){}
    void b(int val){}
};

class B {
public :
    void b(float val){}
};

// --- Has function a() without arguments

template <typename T, typename = void> struct has_a : std::false_type
{
};

template <typename T> struct has_a<T, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().a())>> : std::true_type
{
};

template <typename T> constexpr bool has_a_v = has_a<T>::value;

// This is OK:
static_assert(true == has_a_v<A>); 
static_assert(false == has_a_v<B>);

// --- Has function b() with one argument of one given type

template <typename T, typename U, typename = void> struct has_b : std::false_type
{
};

template <typename T ,typename U> struct has_b<T, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().b(std::declval<U>()))>> : std::true_type
{
};

template <typename T, typename U> constexpr bool has_b_v = has_b<T, U>::value;

// This fails with `template parameters not deducible in partial specialization`:
static_assert(true == has_b_v<A, int>);
static_assert(false == has_b_v<B, int>);

static_assert(false == has_b_v<A, float>);
static_assert(true == has_b_v<B, float>);

int main () { return 0;}
```

Comment: You have a typo. `std::declval<T>().b(std::declval(U))` should be `std::declval<T>().b( std::declval<U>())`

Comment: @Caiwan You have another typo - partial specialization of `has_b` needs to have three template parameters: `<T, U, std::void_t...>`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Example of a  `void_t` check for member function `b` in class `B`:

```
decltype( static_cast<void(B::*)(float)>(&B::b) )
```

This is if you want to check for *exact* signature. Your way is fine, too (once you fix it as commented under the question), but it actually checks if member function is *callable* with certain types of arguments (and ignores the return type).

Answer (score 2):

In your partial specialization, you forgot to add the `U` parameter:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct has_b<
    T,
    U, // You forgot it
    std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().b(std::declval<U>()))>> : std::true_type
{
};
```